# Running automation on buttons in span class

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I have to prepare automation test cases using Selenium for the signup/login process of the website: https://redmart.com/ 
While using Selenium IDE of Firefox I am able to find the button using xpath (On clicking the Find button the searched button gets highlighted with yellow color) but during the execution of test case it's unable to click either the login button or the signup one. The html code for the button (which one can find out using inspect element):

```
<div id="signin">
<a href="/signup" data-bypass="true" class="signinBtn button">
<span>Log in</span>
</a>
<a href="/signup" data-bypass="true" class="signupBtn button">
<span>Sign up</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
open https://redmart.com/
pause 5000
click xpath=//div[@id='signin']/a[1]
```

The signup element location provided by IDE is: "css=a.signupBtn.button > span". It uses css intead of xpath but it works.

I tried this code in Java and it works too:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
  driver.get("https://redmart.com/");
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='signin']/a[1]")).click(); //click to login button
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='signin']/a[2]")).click(); //click to signup button
  driver.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below script, it worked fine

```
   <tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>http://redmart.com/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>css=a.signinBtn.button &gt; span</td>
    <td>Log in</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>css=a.signupBtn.button &gt; span</td>
    <td>Sign up</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=a.signinBtn.button &gt; span</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>name=email</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=email</td>
    <td>test@redmart.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=password</td>
    <td>1234567</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>css=button.signinBtn.button</td>
    <td>Log In</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=button.signinBtn.button</td>
    <td></td>   
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>css=a.signupBtn.button &gt; span</td>
    <td>Sign up</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=a.signupBtn.button &gt; span</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>id=signupBar</td>
    <td>Three Reasons to Sign Up 1. Easy re-order <br /> with RedMart <br /> 2.             
                 Delivery 7 days a <br /> week in Singapore <br /> 3. Enjoy great       
                   discounts on our products <br /> <br /> Sign Up</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>css=#topBarSignUpForm &gt; input[name=&quot;email&quot;]</td>
    <td>etest</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>css=#topBarSignUpForm &gt; input[name=&quot;password&quot;]</td>
    <td>3432432`</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>name=password_confirm</td>
    <td>324324</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=button.signup.button</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```